# Disproving that a particular space is Banach

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure and $1\leq p_1<p_2<\infty$. Consider the linear space $L^{p_2}(E)$ normed by $\|.\|_{p_1}$. Is this normed linear space a Banach space?

My professor hinted that the answer was no. So I developed the following example, taking $p_1=1$ and $p_2=2$: let $E=(0,1)$. Let the cauchy sequence of $L^{2}$ functions with respect to the $\|.\|_{1}$ norm be $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,\frac{1}{n})$, and $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x\in(\frac{1}{n},1)$.

With respect to the $\|.\|_1$ norm, it converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, which is not an $L^2$ function over $(0,1)$. However, how do I show that there is no $L^2$ function such that $\{f_n\}$ converges to it with respect to the $\|.\|_1$ norm?

Comment: If $f_n\to f$ in a norm then that limit is unique. So you don't have anything to show, if I am reading your question correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $g$ is the limit of $\{f_n\}$ for the $\|.\|_1$ norm. We can extract an almost everywhere convergent subsequence to this $g$. For each $a\in (0,1)$ and $x\in (a,1)$, we have $f_n(x)=1/\sqrt x$ hence we should have $g(x)=1/\sqrt x$ which implies that for all $x\in (0,1)$, $g(x)=1/\sqrt x$. Therefore, the only possible candidate does not do the job, since $g$ is not an element of $L^2$.